# How to display API data by using multiple returned data from multiple API's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, api

I have successfully figured out how to display singular API data but have faced an issue. 
- I am trying to use the following API to return the data of "data" using the "following" shown in the next API example.

For this to be completed, two following API's are used.

- is used to return "data" to be further used to retrieve "Following data" in the API in question.
- is used to get the "data" to access the "following data" previously.

Sorry, I am very stuck and have no idea what I have done wrong. Below is my attempted code, I hope this is helpful and explained well.

```
          let response1 = await $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '',
          });
          let response2 = await $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: ''
          });
          let response3 = await $.ajax({
            method: 'GET',
            url: ''
          });
          const result = response3.find(item => item.ID === response2.result === response1.result.codes)
          console.log(result.ID);
        })();
```

Comment: Hi Rodger,
What is the error you are getting? It helps a lot to know both what you want to have happen and what is going wrong.

Comment: Look at the error in the console. `response2` is an array of objects, therefore you need to loop through it and or pull out a specific object in that array. In either case you need to access `response2.result` by index.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes I saw from the browser console but I was unsure how to code that into this example due to being new to ajax etc

Comment: I cant seem to edit the post so here is the errors @NegativieFriction  Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'ConstituencyCode' of undefined
    at msp2test.php:23
    at Array.find (<anonymous>)
    at msp2test.php:23

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get results from your `$.ajax` requests.

```js
let response1 = $.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.postcodes.io/scotland/postcodes/FK15LD',
});

let response2 = $.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://data.parliament.scot/api/constituencies'
});

function response3(id) {

  return $.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://data.parliament.scot/api/MemberElectionConstituencyStatuses/' + id
  });
}

let resp3 = response3(2);
resp3.then(function(res3) {
  console.log(res3);
});

// Or
// I'm not sure where you want to get the ID from for your third request, but

response1.then(function(res1) {
  // do something with res1
  response2.then(function() {
    // do something with res2
    let resp3 = response3(2); // or response3(res2[0].id);
    resp3.then(function(res3) {
      // do something with res3
      console.log(res3);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```